# How to get rid of the "ears" in the bottom of the screen?

Tags: macos, dock, desktop

I have a mild form of OCD so by ears I mean this:

[image]

I know that I can hide the dock, but then I do not see the opened programs.

What solutions are available to extend the opaque dock background to the edges of the screen so that visually it is a wider bar matching the screen width?

On a Windows machine you have a notification area wth clock and date in the "right ear" and the start button and search etc. in the "left ear".

Comment: What do you mean by ear ? even with the photo I still don't get it

Comment: @maetsoh Hi, I have updated my question with a new image. Please, check it now.

Comment: You could edit your wallpaper image to have a stripe along the bottom that's the same height and color as the dock.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow, I have found this:

http://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar

This looks like the Windows 7 taskbar I was using and loving for so long. Great!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5XDS6V3Ce0

Now I just need to move the top menu to the actual windows of the program, the current sticky position reminds me my TOS but I think the way of menu being with the window of the app is much better.

Comment: Why the down vote? This program solve my problem with the "ears" completely

Comment: Explaining down votes is optional. Maybe somebody was wondering why you put so much effort into changing the way OSX works into the way Windows works. Or just had a bad day.

Comment: Because it's more efficient that way. In windows you have just one bar and everything is there. On Mac it's the same. That's why I prefer on Linux desktop environments like KDE, Cinnamon, Mate, Xfce, Lxde and don't like Unity, Gnome, Pantheon, etc. Why have 2 bars if one is enough? This is what I don't like on OS X, the top menu and multitasking problems it brings. In Windows or KDE you see the menu of the windows you have open right away and you can click drectly to the menu, e.g. edit without swithcing the program at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you put the dock on the left- or right-hand side of the screen instead of at the bottom, the unused space around it will be much smaller.

Comment: Like in Ubuntu?

Comment: @JohnDoerthy I have no idea -- I administer hundreds of Ubuntu machines, but don't run a GUI on any of them.

Comment: I am a big fan of the dock on the sides. It removes the "ear effect" and gives back full height to window content.

Answer (score 1):

The dock is a different beast than the Windows task bar in XP and before. it is designed to hold **ALL** of your preferred applications rather than just the running ones. It is, however similar to the Vista/Win7/8/10 task bar but leaves out out the Start menu and system tray.

Notifications don't show up in the system tray, rather in the Notification center which will display a pop-up on the right side of the screen (starting at the top). The clock will display in the menu bar if you configure it to do so.

Your so called "ears" is just blank desktop to either side of the dock and if that empty space bothers you, you could either do the Dock show/hide preference or fill the dock so full with apps and documents that it fills the screen side to side.

There are also Dock alternatives out there if you don't like the one that comes with Mac OS.

Comment: What dock alternative allows a full width opaque area?

Comment: [StatusDuck](http://www.statusduck.com/index.html) seems to be a nice alternative. And I can hide the dock completely. Or do you know about something better?